# Display fonts in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts

I need to display installed fonts on WP7. Is there any simple way to do that?
As of now I am trying to bind font names and listing using ListPicker but that's not actually I need.

I need to find the fonts listed on the WP7 and display them in the ListPicker full screen mode.

This is what I have now:

**Data Template**:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFontNames">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FontNames}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

**ListPicker: **

```
<toolkit:ListPicker FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFontNames}"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lpkFontName" Width="290" Height="63" FullModeHeader="Selct Font Name"/>
```

And in the codebehind:

```
Dim FontNames() As String = { "Arial","Segoe UI", "Times New Roman", "Cambria"}

Me.lpkFontName.ItemsSource = FontNames
```

**EDIT: **

I followed [this](http://blog.saraf.me/2012/01/wp7-custom-font-picker.html) but I am unable to populate them

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `DataTemplate` - your `TextBlock`'s binding won't have a "FontNames" property. For each item in the `ListPicker`'s `ItemsSource` an instance of your `DataTemplate` will be created and bound to that item in the `ItemsSource`. What you want to do is bind the properties of the `TextBlock` directly to the item the `DataTemplate` has been created for. Eg;

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFontNames">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
               FontFamily="{Binding}"
               />
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm presuming that you want the font name to display in the font itself, as per [Custom Font Picker](http://blog.saraf.me/2012/01/wp7-custom-font-picker.html) ? If not, drop the `FontFamily` attribute from the `TextBlock` in your `DataTemplate`. Eg;

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFontNames">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
               />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: @MrMDavidson-Thanks for your reply and I got it working and If I need to get the selected font what do I need to do?So that I need to get similar to this:textbox1.text=ListPicker.SelectedFont.Can I do something like this to get the selected font.

Comment: You can get the currently selected item of a `ListPicker` by using the `SelectedItem` property. As this is an object you will need to cast it to the appropriate type (`string` in your case). If you have multiple select enabled you can get an `IList` via the `SelectedItems` (Note the **s**) property. Again, would need to cast each item appropriately.